# the most effective procedure to trace a scanned sewing pattern?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace, live-trace, technical-drawing

This is the type of the image I am hoping to autotrace

[image: sewing pattern piece]

I have gotten to the point of tracing in Adobe Illustrator as stroke. Obvously the text tracing doesn't work and I will need to retype it or run it through OCR separately, but all the arrows and rombs on the pattern do not come out correctly when traced as a stroke. What would be a best procedure for tracing something like that? What would be the best procedure for **preparing** the piece for tracing, other than ironing the paper? Anything I need to do in Photoshop? Or will it truly be faster to hand trace with a pen tool?

Thank you for your help.

[image: autotraced image]

Comment: Quite honestly, I'd place the photo, lock the layer, create a new layer and then *manually* recreate it. Tracing is *never* precise regardless of any settings.

Comment: any tips for dealing with the text?

Comment: It would all need to be re-keyed. Then it's just a skew/rotate a bit.

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea. So while there is a bit of work to draw this again. It pales to compariasion in you needing to verify that your scan is proper- So for example Is this scanned with a flatbed scanner. Did you calibrate your scanner? So its often easier to just get a ruler and measure the points. For example your seam allowances in the image seem to indicate that theres quite the distortion in your image to begin with

Comment: Trying to fix a substandard autotrace of a somewhat wonky image will take longer than redrawing it manually.  Can I also suggest you try to flatten the paper, use a flat bed scanner, plus avoid cutting off part of the image. This will make the job easier.